# jQuery check that file upload is an mp3

Tags: javascript, regex, file, upload, submit

Using a regex to make sure a file that's being uploaded through `input[type="file"]` is an MP3. Somethings going wrong, the files that I'm testing with arn't passing.

Thanks for your help!

HTML

```
<input type="file"/>
```

JavaScript

```
var file = $input.find('input[type="file"]'),
    val  = file.val(),
    type = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)(\.mp3)$/;

submit.attr('disabled', 'disabled').addClass('deac');

if (!val){

    modal("The upload can't be empty.", true);
} else if (!type.test(val)){

    modal("The song must be in MP3 format.", true);

    /***********
     *
     * Getting caught here- even with a valid .mp3 file that _should_ pass the regex
     * in my test case using mamp as a localhost, val = C:\fakepath\1.mp3 
     *
     ***********/
} else {

    /* Success */
}
```

Comment: If "val" is "C:\fakepath\1.mp3", then it's clear why it's not passing - the regex does not allow ":" or "\".

Comment: Also you probably should allow upper-case "MP3", in case somebody's uploading from a FAT filesystem. (Of course your server should check the actual file contents if it's really important to ensure that only real MP3 files are uploaded; the filename can be trivially spoofed.)

Comment: @Pointy regex's are way beyond me, they look like gibberish. mind answering below with a suggestion so that I can give you credit and knock this one off my list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think IE is the only browser that adds anything like the "fakepath" prefix, so something like this might work better:

```
type = /^(?:[A-Z]:\\fakepath\\)?([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)(\.[Mm][Pp]3)$/;
```

Comment: no dice- getting the same failure local and hosted. fwiw it looks like val is still including the fakepath address on the server

Comment: @technopeasant yes and there's nothing you can do about that unfortunately - let me check the regex and I'll update

Comment: @technopeasant sorry I had skipped a backslash.  Now that I think about it, getting the "fakepath" part on the server seems a little weird; I'll have to check my own code to see if I ever do that.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution is to use the method [mime()](http://www.jquerysdk.com/api/jQuery.mime).

In this way, even if the file is renamed with a. Mp3 is not circumvented control.

Comment: great idea, just hesitate to include the sdk for one simple check

Comment: You're right!
``$('input[type="file"]').prop('files')[0].file;`` so extract the mime type of the file and you can check it.
In this way you do not have to import all the sdk!

Comment: @loughino returns undefined local and hosted